# Given a large database of over 50,000 , How can I quickly search for desired points

Tags: data-structures

I have a database of over 50,000 points. Each point has 3 dimensions. Let's label them [i,j,k]

I wish to look for points in which it is better than another point in some other way.

For example, Object A [10 10 3], and Object B[1 1 4], Object C[1 1 1], Object D[1 1 10]

Then the desired output would be A and D (since C is worser than all of them, and B beats A in dimenson[k] but D beats B in dimension [k])

I've tried some basic comparison algorithms (i.e. if else statements) which do work when I cut down the database size. But with 50,000, it takes more than 10mins to find the desired output, which of course is not a good solution.

Could somebody recommend me a method or two to do this the fastest possible way?

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks I think I've got it

Comment: What is a "desired point" in this context? What is the algorithm / query you are currently using that is not performance satisfactory?

Comment: The description of "desired output" is not quite clear, would you mind to rephrase and clarify the description?

Comment: Looks like you're selecting pareto-optimal points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do many optimizations to your code:

```
{
vector<bool> isinterst(n, true);

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {


    if (isinterst[i]) {
        bool worseelsewhere=false;

        for (int k=0; k<d; k++)
        {
            if (point[i][k]<point[j][k])
            {
                worseelsewhere=true; 
                break;   //you can exit for loop if worseelsewhere is set to true
            }
        }                          
        if(worseelsewhere == false)
        {
              continue; //skip the rest if worseelsewhere is false
        }

        bool worse=true;
        for (int k=0; k<d; k++)
        {
            if (point[i][k]>point[j][k])
            {
                worse=false;
                break; //you can exit for loop if worse is set to false
            }
        }

        if (worseelsewhere && worse) {
            isinterst[i]=false;
            //cout << i << " Not desirable " << endl; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for pareto-optimal points. These form a convex hull. That's easiest to see in 2 dimensions. Use an iterative algorithm to determine the pareto-optimal points of the first N points. For N=1, that's just the first point. For N=2, the next point is either dominated by the first (discard 2nd), dominates the 1st (discard 1st), lies above to the left, or below to the right (and so is also pareto-optimal).

You can speed up classification by keeping a simplified upper and lower bound for the convex hull, e.g. just single points `{minX, minY, minZ}` and `{maxX, maxY, maxZ}`. If `P={x,y,z}` is dominated by `{minX, minY, minZ}` then it is dominated by all pareto-optimal points so far and can be discarded. If P dominates `{maxX, maxY, maxZ}`, it also dominates all points that were pareto-optimal so far and you can discard all those.

A quick O(log N) initial step is to first sort the collection in X order to find the point with max X, then Y to find the point with max Y, and finally with max Z. Finding the pareto-optimal points in ths N=3 subset is easy, and can be hardcoded. You can then use this set as a first approximation.

A more refined solution is to then sort by `X+Y`, `X+Z`, `Y+Z` and `X+Y+Z` and find those maxima as well. Again, this produces points which are good initial candidates because they will dominate many other points.

E.g. in your case, sorting by X and sorting by Y would both produce point A; sorting by Z would produce point D, neither dominates the other, and you can then quickly discard B and C.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your definition of "better" it's a bit hard to make concrete suggestions here. I note, however, that you appear to working with spatial data. A data structure that is often used when working with spatial data is the R-Tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). This provides an efficient index for multidimensional information.

Perhaps the boost::geometry library has some tools that will assist: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/introduction.html